# onclick event is not firing from repeater in aspx page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am searching character wise records from repeater.But while clicking button it's not responding or event is not firing.Debugging button is not coming while clicking.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptAlphabets" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Value")%>' Visible='<%# !Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Selected"))%>'
               OnClick="alphabetClick_Click" />
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Value")%>' Visible='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Selected"))%>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>



 protected void alphabetClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lnkAlphabet = (LinkButton)sender;
        ViewState["CurrentAlphabet"] = lnkAlphabet.Text;
        this.GenerateAlphabets();
        gvPaymentstatus.PageIndex = 0;
        this.BindGrid();

    }
```

Comment: please rebuild new "link button "

Comment: Didn't use aspx in a while, but I think the method is case sensitive, your protected void alphabetClick_Click should be AlphabetClick_Click

Comment: why like that i have  OnClick="alphabetClick_Click" .

Comment: What does the renderd html look like , are you missing a form or something?

Comment: i already used form1.in that i kept repeater

Comment: You have OnClick="alphabetClick_Click"  with lower case, at least in what you posted here...

Comment: i dnt know what are u saying . both are in same case. started with small lette and its generated automatically

Comment: You edited the question to fix the problem that @ZivWeissman is talking about. Presumably he made his comment before you edited it. It's sort of weird that you're acting like you don't know what he's talking about, when you obviously saw the same problem, since you edited it...

Comment: Anyway, based on what's posted here, I don't see anything that's obviously wrong. Is a postback even occurring when you click the link?

Comment: no its not firning any event . i put debug points in all events. but its not firing. even page is not refreshing

Comment: Hey I am only trying to help you... anyway, I would try this: remove all eval from LinkButton, use static text for now, build your project and try debug (make sure you are on 'debug' and not 'release', there is no reason this code should not work.

Comment: use example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcommand(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i got error...Uncaught TypeError: theForm.submit is not a function..in client side. thats why its not posting. how to handle this

Comment: problem solved. in one place i have used this due to this its not posting.<input name="submit" value="Submit" type="submit">. sorry the error was not in that code . thanks for ur helping.